# Char pointer pointing to char array instead of single char?

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, char

When I use a char pointer to point to a single char it seems to end up pointing to a char array instead. What's going wrong here??

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <map>

 using namespace std;

 int main() {

     char first = 'a';
     char second = 'b';
     char third = 'c';

     map<char, char *> myMap;

     myMap['a'] = &first;
     myMap['b'] = &second;
     myMap['c'] = &third;

     cout << myMap['a'] << endl; // ends up printing 'abc' or 'cba'

     system("pause");
     return 0;    
 }
```

Comment: If this didn't happen, `std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";` would print `H`, and that would be mighty confusing for beginners.

Comment: If you pass a `char *` to an `iostream`, it assumes it's a C-style string.

Comment: @chris Actually, it would print something like `0x4f72b6d4` - it wouldn't have a single reason to derefernce the pointer then.

Comment: @Angew, I was just thinking about that >.> Oh well, I'll leave it for the world to see my comment-before-thinking.

Comment: @chris That back-and-forth actually really clarified what's happening = )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`operator<<` overload for `char*` expects a pointer to a null terminated array of characters so that it knows where the string  ends. It just so happens that your `char` variables were allocated contiguously in memory and that a 0 byte follows them. The code invokes undefined behaviour though.

To print a single char, dereference the pointer:

```
cout << *myMap['a'] << endl;
```